# C1FlexGrid - How to update grid from BindingSource when underlying IEnumerable changes values

Tags: c#, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have the following POCO object:

```
    internal class StationEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;
    private string _stationType;
    private string _stationName;

    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _id) return;
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public string StationType
    {
        get { return _stationType; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _stationType) return;
            _stationType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StationType");
        }
    }

    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public string StationName
    {
        get { return _stationName; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _stationName) return;
            _stationName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("StationName");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I set the grid's data source as a BindingSource and set the binding source as follows:

```
            gridStations.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            stationEntityBindingSource.DataSource = _stations;
            gridStations.DataSource = stationEntityBindingSource;
```

Note that _stations is a `List<StationEntity>`.  If I bind directly against _stations, the grid will not raise delete events, but it does when I use the BindingSource.  In my deletes I renumber the collection:

```
        private void gridStations_BeforeDeleteRow(object sender, C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row < 0 || e.Row > _stations.Count)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        var row = gridStations.Rows[e.Row];
        if (row.DataSource != null)
        {
            var _toDelete = row.DataSource as StationEntity;
        }
    }

    private void gridStations_AfterDeleteRow(object sender, C1.Win.C1FlexGrid.RowColEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_toDelete.IsNotNull())
        {
            _stations.Remove(_toDelete);

            var station = 1;

            foreach (var item in _stations)
            {
                item.ID = station++;
            }

            stationEntityBindingSource.DataSource = null;
            gridStations.Update();
            stationEntityBindingSource.DataSource = _stations;
            gridStations.Update();

            _toDelete = null;
        }
    }
```

Even after clearing the DataSource of the BindingSource and reapplying it, the grid still doesn't show the updated values.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to notify collection changed to listen to add delete events. the property changed only triggers when the value changes.

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid.  The line in BeforeDelete that assigns _toDelete is using a local variable declaration which is preventing the instance variable _toDelete from being set.  After fixing that the code works fine with the suggestion in the answer.

Comment: @PaytonByrd Please post your revised answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (_toDelete.IsNotNull())
        {
            _stations.Remove(_toDelete);

            var station = 1;

            foreach (var item in _stations)
            {
                item.ID = station++;
            }

            stationEntityBindingSource.DataSource = null;
            gridStations.Update();
            stationEntityBindingSource.DataSource = _stations;

            //add this line
            gridStations.DataSource = null;
            gridStations.DataSource = stationEntityBindingSource;

            _toDelete = null;
        }
```

Comment: Check whether `_stations.Remove(_toDelete);` actually removed the item?

Comment: Yes, the delete is working, it's the renumbering that does not reflect in the grid.

Comment: Please see updated answer. I think it needs `gridStations.DataSource = null;`